# sharepoint new item form with multiple submit button + sharepoint designer

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I am having 150 columns grouped in to 10 groups in a single new form.

I want to submit first group and update the next groups individually in a single form with individual save buttons.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

you can customise the form, and then create multiple panels and place fields in each panel

then create previous and next buttons to go forward and back, showing the current panel and hiding all others

as for saving, you can keep the save button outside the panels so it is available all the time. but you will still have to figure out the action for saving in case the user has not completed all pages. maybe you can redirect to the same page, using querystrings, or just dont save partially and show save in the last panel

Comment: Thanks for your reply Tiago Duarte , I got the solution for the Tabbing by following the Following URL : http://arunduttgp.wordpress.com/2010/03/30/sharepoint-custom-list-form-with-tab-style-ui/